# Increase left margin (without setting explicitly)

Tags: spacing, margins, geometry

I am attempting to increase the left margin of my page(s) by a specific amount (10 pt) but this functionality does not seem to exist in the `geometry` package. Every answer I've seen that refers to changing the left margin recommends setting it explicitly by doing

```
\usepackage[left=XXpt]{geometry}
```

or

```
\newgeometry{left=XXpt}
```

This is with the exception of one answer which talked about using the `\addtolength` command. This would be ideal except I have tried this with several length names formed as variations of the words "left" and "margin" as its argument but none had the desired result (moving the text out from what it was by 10 pt).

Can anyone inform me of the best/recommended method of doing this? If it involves using `\addtolength`, what is the name of the length given as the argument?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You might take a loo,ar the `changepage` package and its `adjustwidth` environment.

Comment: please rephrase your question. it is not very clear. do you like to change left margin only for some paragraph (image, table, equation) or for one whole page or for whole document. package `geometry` doesn't enable to change of existing margin for some amount. you should define new value for it. however you change margins for some amount with help of package `changepage` as mentioned @Bernard in his comment. but this changes has some restriction. provide please some example in form of small, but complete document, which will clarify your question.

Comment: If you are not using any lists (which includes a lot of stuff not generally thought of as lists) you can set \leftskip.  If you don't need to break pages, you can use `\noindent\hspace{...}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-...}`  You might consider creating you own list environment.

Answer (score 2):

as far as I can tell you are looking for

```
\addtolength\textwidth{-10pt}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{10pt}
\addtolength\evensidemargin{10pt}
```

the last line only being needed if you are using a `twoside` documentclass setting with separate settings for odd and even pages.